# Swift: Subclassing UITextView or UICollectionView and proper initialization

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextview, swift

The problem with subclassing UITextView (and UICollectionView) is that designated constructor is "initWithFrame". But in real life, when it loads from storyboard, initWithCoder will be called.

```
class BorderedTextView: UITextView {
    //will be called
    init(coder: NSCoder?){
       //constant values here is not an option
       super.init(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100), textContainer: nil)
    }
    //will not be called
    init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer!) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
    }
}
```

As result I cannot call any UI customisation code on init and provide any initialization value for Swift variables except defaults.

I suppose that problem can be temporary solved by extracting frame size from "coder", but I didn't found the key for it.

Any ideas better than hardcode frame values?

Comment: I would expect that `super.init(coder: coder)` works - and for subclasses of UIView or UILabel it does (at least the compiler does not complain). But for subclasses of `UITextView` it fails with an error message "Must call designated initializer ...". A Swift bug?

Comment: A possible workaround could be to do the initialization in `awakeFromNib` instead.

Comment: You right, looks like it works for UIView (I updated question). But I also have same problem with UICollectionView, so the problem is not only with UITextView.

Comment: The difference seems to be that both UITextView and UICollectionView have their "own" designated initializer (in contrast to e.g. UILabel). I still think that this is a Swift bug (and should be reported to Apple), because the same pattern works in Objective-C.

Comment: Filed it to apple. Thank you for `awakeFromNib` workaround, it perfectly fits my current requirements.

Comment: @AlexeySuvorov Please don't forget to accept Martin R's answer, so that everyone knows this question has a correct answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*(From my above comments:)* This looks like a Swift bug. `initWithCoder:` is called when
a view (or view controller) is instantiated from a Storyboard or Nib file, and overriding
that method works in Objective-C:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

But the equivalent Swift code

```
class BorderedTextView: UITextView {
    init(coder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

fails with the error message "must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UITextView'".

This problem occurs with all subclasses of `UIView` that have a
their own designated initializer (e.g. `UITextView`, `UICollectionView`).
On the other hand, the problem does not occur with subclasses of `UILabel`, which
does not have a designated initializer.
The Swift language is very strict about calling the super classes' designated initializer,
but there should be a way to override `initWithCoder:` for all custom `UIView` subclasses, so I consider this a Swift bug.

As a workaround, you can do the custom initialisation in

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // ...
}
```

---

**Update for Swift 1.2:** This apparently has been fixed. The parameter
changed, it is no longer an implicitly unwrapped optional. So this
compiles and works as expected (tested with Xcode 6.4):

```
class BorderedTextView: UITextView {
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        // ...
    }
}
```

---

**Update for Swift 2 (Xcode 7):** `init(coder:)` is a failable
initializer now:

```
class BorderedTextView: UITextView {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A more complete answer for Swift 3:

```
class ValidatedTextField:UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    required override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        //custom code
        self.delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        //custom code
        self.delegate = self
    }
```

Comment: The OP asks about UITextView not UITextField.